# Horário de verão TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server

Após a mudança do horário de verão o burndown dos projetos não aparece mais, como mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ao clicar no Burndown ocorre a mensagem: "Error(s):

The chart could not be generated."

Obs: O problema só ocorre para a sprint corrente.

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português, vulgo SOpt. Para melhor compreensão da sua pergunta coloque o trecho de código referente a ela, descreva o que está tentando fazer o qual o problema que está enfrentando. Também vou editar sua pergunta retirando seus comprimentos, no formato da SOpt evitamos esse uso já que as pessoas que vão ler a pergunta posteriormente podem estar em horários diferente da pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um problema conhecido desde o ano passado e envolve base de dados... Talvez por isso tenha voltado a acontecer e não sei se tem solução.
Mas tem um workaround para resolver: o horário de verão não pode estar no meio da sua sprint ou iteração. Se você terminar a sprint na sexta ou sábado e iniciar a próxima na segunda, vai ver que o problema não vai aparecer. Pode mudar só mudar as datas que resolve, não precisa recriar.